# How to avoid losing values of textbox of a first page when click to next page - webgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

`ASP.NET MVC 4 and C#` - I need to know how to avoid a refresh `webgrid` page when click next page without losing values of `textbox` (txtMessage). My problem is that when I input values in some Message `textbox` in a first page and then click the next page and go back to the first page, the values are gone. **How to keep values no matter how times you click next page or go back.** I have been trying to find solution on Google but I am lost how to solve it.

```
@{

Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
var grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 100, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "gridcontent");
 }

  <div id="gridcontent" >

    @grid.GetWebGrid(
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "grid-header",
    footerStyle: "grid-footer",
    selectedRowStyle: "rid-selected-row",
    alternatingRowStyle:"grid-alternating-row",
    rowStyle: "grid-row-style",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.FirstLast | WebGridPagerModes.Numeric | WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious,
    numericLinksCount: 5,
    firstText: "<< First",
    previousText: "< Previous",
    lastText: "Last >>",
    nextText: "Next >",
    columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column(columnName: "AnimalId", header: "Animal ID", style: "colId", format: (item) => string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.AnimalId) ? string.Empty : item.AnimalId),
        grid.Column(columnName: "MessageValue", header: "Message", format: (item) => Html.TextBox("txtMessage", (object)item.MessageValue), canSort: false,),

             grid.Column(header: "View Details", format: @<text><input id="btnView " type="button" value="Details" /></text>),
              ))

  </div>
```

Comment: use `ViewData[]` to avoid losing

Comment: really? maybe you can give me a nice example?

Comment: try storing the values of the textbox in session, and populating that textbox from session each time that page is navigated too. The first time a person goes to that page just check if session is null and don't populate, else populate from session